# How can I set a range using the value of a cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I am having a little trouble tweaking my google script.  I have shown part of it below and I will try to explain what I am trying to do.  Below is a part of the script:

```
function setup() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
for (i = 1; i <= 1; i++) { 
var sheet = ss.insertSheet('Final Grades');
    sheet.getRange("A2").setFormula("=arrayformula(if(ISBLANK(Grades!A9:A96),, vlookup(Grades!A9:A96, Grades!A9:G96, 4, FALSE)))");
```

I am trying to replace the range in the ISBLANK and vlookup commands based on the total entries.  I have a cell, located in 'Grades' sheet in cell B5  that contains the total number of entries.  What I am trying to do is have the script take that value in B5 and add it to the range in the ISBLANK and vlookup commands.

Right now the range is A9:A96 for both the ISBLANK and vlookup, but what I am trying to accomplish is to take that value located in B5 (let's say its 80) so that the new line would be:

```
sheet.getRange("A2").setFormula("=arrayformula(if(ISBLANK(Grades!A9:A89),, vlookup(Grades!A9:A89, Grades!A9:G89, 4, FALSE)))");
```

The second part of the range in ISBLANK and vlookup has changed based upon the value of B5 (in this case 80.)  Is this even possible?  If so, how would I do this?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means you should compose the formula string dynamically, based on the value of B5. For readability of code, I suggest doing this step by step:

```
var endRow = sheet.getRange("B5").getValue() + 9;
var formula = "=arrayformula(if(ISBLANK(Grades!A9:A" + endRow + ",, vlookup(Grades!A9:A" + endRow + ", Grades!A9:G" + endRow + ", 4, FALSE)))";
sheet.getRange("A2").setFormula(formula);
```

As a result, the number 96 is replaced by endRow on every occasion.

Comment: Marshmellow, thank you so much.  I used your var's and applied them to my script and it works beautifully.  I was wondering if you could explain the reason for the + after you added the endRow var.  In other words:      Grades!A9:A" + endRow + "  <-- why the 2nd plus sign?

Comment: + means concatenation of strings in this context. Like "A" + 32 + "BC" makes "A32BC". See [addition operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition_()).

Comment: So in my example if endRow = 80, then would this work:  Grades!A9:A" + endRow"  Would that not equal this:  Grades!A9:A89.  I don't understand the need for the 2nd + sign.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: But is Grades!A9:A89 the end of the formula? Don't you want something else after that, like other arguments, commas and parentheses? That's what the other + leads to.. I recommend [JavaScript course from Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/javascript).

Comment: Marshmellow, thanks again for the explanations and help.  Learned a ton from this small bit of code.

Comment: No problem. On Stack Exchange, the answer that worked for you can  be marked "accepted" by  clicking the checkmark next to it.